# How to stop pressing a key after using keybd_event?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard

I a problem using  [`keybd_event`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx) function. When I call it to press Ctrl once:

```
keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0x9C,0,0);
```

then if I call it to press X key, it will press Ctrl+X. For example, the next line is:

```
keybd_event(0x43,0x9C,0,0);  //0x43 is the Virtual-Key Code of 'C' key
```

So, it will copy the text (Ctrl+C) not type the letter 'C'. Actually, it does not stop pressing Ctrl, even after closing the program. So how can I stop pressing Ctrl key anymore? I have the same problem with Shift key.

Comment: Does it stop if you send `keybd_event(VK_CONTROL,0x1C,0,0);` or you use the `KEYEVENTF_KEYUP` flag?

Comment: @MargaretBloom No, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your own link - `keybd_event` function has `KEYEVENTF_UP` flag:

> KEYEVENTF_KEYUP 0x0002 If specified, the key is being released. If not
>   specified, the key is being depressed.